# Replace property attribute with a normal attribute

Tags: python, properties

Is it possible to replace a property of an object with 'normal' attribute?

I need this because when I access the attribute for the first, I want the value to be generated by the property. But I no longer need the property afterward:

```
class A(object):
    @property
    def x(self):
         self.x = "toto"   # Replace property, fail because no setter
         return self.x 

a = A()
print a.x # "toto"
a.x = "tata"
```

I know I can store the value in a second attribute like `_x`and check in the property if `_x` exist but I want to know if it's possible the replace the property itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To bypass the lack of a setter, you'd have to directly manipulate the instance `__dict__` dictionary. However, you can't do what you want with a regular `property` object, because it is a [*data descriptor*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol). Attribute access will *always* give a data descriptor priority over instance attributes.

You'd have to create a custom descriptor instead, one that doesn't define a `__set__` or `__delete__` method:

```
class CachingProperty(object):
    def __init__(self, fget):
        self.name = fget.__name__
        self.fget = fget

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        value = self.fget(instance)
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value
        return value
```

This descriptor also takes care of setting the value directly in the instance `__dict__` attribute, thus creating an instance attribute.

Use the above class instead of `property`:

```
class A(object):
    @CachingProperty
    def x(self):
         return "toto"
```

Demo, showing that the getter method is only called once:

```
>>> class Demo(object):
...     @CachingProperty
...     def foo(self):
...         print("Calling the foo property")
...         return "bar"
...
>>> d = Demo()
>>> d.foo
Calling the foo property
'bar'
>>> d.foo
'bar'
>>> vars(d)
{'foo': 'bar'}
```